# Linregress output seems incorrect

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I plotted a scatter plot on my dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

with code

```
from scipy import stats   
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/df.csv', sep=',') 
subset = df[:,1:10080]   
df['mean'] = subset.mean(axis=1)

df.plot(x='mean', y='Result', kind = 'scatter')
sns.lmplot('mean', 'Result', df, order=1)
```

I wanted to find the slope of the regression in the graph using code

```
scipy.stats.mstats.linregress(Result,average)
```

but from the output it seems like the slope magnitude is too small:

```
LinregressResult(slope=-0.0001320534706614152, intercept=27.887336813241845, rvalue=-0.16776138446214162, pvalue=3.0450456899520655e-07, stderr=2.55977061451773e-05)
```

if I switched the `Result`and `average` positions,

```
scipy.stats.mstats.linregress(average,Result)
```

it still doesn't look right as the `intercept` is too large

```
LinregressResult(slope=-213.12489536011773, intercept=7138.48783135982, rvalue=-0.16776138446214162, pvalue=3.0450456899520655e-07, stderr=41.31287437069993)
```

Why is this happening? Do these output values need to be rescaled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for `scipy.stats.mstats.linregress` is `linregress(x,y)` so your second ordering, `linregress(average, Result)` is the one that is consistent with the way your graph is drawn.  And on that graph, an intercept of 7138 doesn't seem unreasonable—are you getting confused by the fact that the x-axis limits you're showing don't go down to 0, where the intercept would actually happen?

In any case, your data really don't look like they follow a linear law, so the slope (or any parameter from a completely-misspecified model) will not actually tell you much.  Are the x and y values all strictly positive?  And is there a particular reason why x can never logically go below 25?   The data-points certainly seem to be piling up against that vertical asymptote.  If so, I would probably subtract 25 from x,  then fit a linear model to logged data.  In other words, do your `plot` and your `linregress` with `x=numpy.log(average-25)` and `y=numpy.log(Result)`. EDIT: since you say x is temperature there’s no logical reason why x can’t go below 25 (it is meaningful to want to extrapolate below 25, for example—and even below 0). Therefore don’t subtract 25, and don’t log x. Just log y.

In your comments you talk about rescaling the slope, and eventually the suspicion emerges that you think this will give you a correlation coefficient. These are different things. The correlation coefficient is about the spread of the points around the line as well as slope. If what you want is correlation, look up the relevant tools using that keyword.

Comment: if you look closely the intercept of 7138 should be closer to the `10000` mark than to the origin(or y = 0) on `y-axis`. But the graph actually shows that the intercept is closer to origin. Besides, the slope magnitude of `-213.12` seems too large(shouldn't it lie between `-1` and `1` instead?)

Comment: On the contrary, your graph doesn't show the intercept at all.  Your y axis is drawn at roughly x=23.   The intercept is not defined as "the place where the line crosses wherever you happen to have chosen to draw the y axis".  Rather, it is defined as the value at x=0.  That's nearly one whole x-axis-extent away from the domain we're currently looking at.

Comment: Oh I missed that, thanks! Then why is the slope magnitude so large?

Comment: The slope also looks plausible to me.  We're looking at x from ~23 to ~57,  so a change of about 34 x-units.  A slope of -213 would dictate that the line should drop by 213*34= ~7200 y-units over the visible range.  It's hard to tell due to the lack of grid-lines and sparsity of y-axis ticks but, ball-park, that seems about right.

Comment: I'm not sure the slope really tells you anything about your data though.  A linear model is clearly not a good model for this dataset.

Comment: Do you know how I could rescale the slope to (-1,1) range? Could you recommend a better model for this data?

Comment: x is ambient temperature(usually >25); y values are bacteria count, so both are strictly positive. Thanks, I will try that!

Comment: Is the `rvalue ` representing correlation coefficient of range (-1,1)?